# Capture the last subfolder of the URL to redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect my urls using htaccess such that:

`http://example.com/my/address/is/xyz/` => `http://example.com/xyz/`

The catch is that the number of subfolders in the URL is dynamic, and I need to redirect always to the last one.

I have tried following but apparently, it doesn't work.

`RewriteRule ^my/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /$2/ [R,NC]`

Any idea what could be the right regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a greedy match to match last folder:

```
RewriteRule ^my/(?:.+/)?([^/]+)/?$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvI9rF/1)